# error CS2012: Cannot open <executable path> access to <executable path denied>

Tags: c#, wpf, build

I was working on a WPF application in Visual Studio 2015 and all went well until unexpectedly the build dropped me the CS2012 error inform me that it cannot access/update the executable in the /Debug directory.

I tried the following and it didn't work:

1. Restart
2. Close VS and open the application again
3. Build->Clean

I couldn't find any solution in the web so I tried:
1. to move the whole project directory to another location.
2. creating a new WPF project and assembling it file by file with copy/pastes.

The weird thing was that in both cases the application worked in the new location. I continued the experimentation (in the original directory) and i tried to build a "Hello World" Console application in the same directory. The result was that the trivial console application didn't work and produced the same problem as the WPF application (CS2012 error).

Since I haven't noticed any activity of another program (i.e., antivirus) trying to quarantine (or changing the file/folder permissions of) this folder, I assume that this has been done by VS somehow but I don't know why. Perhaps it is a bug.

Is anyone has a logical explanation about this problem? And a way to fix it?

Comment: I get the same error message every now and then after installing VS2015 running the same code base in VS2013 I have zero issues.
I usually have to do a Clean, the Build, if that doesn't work I open Task Manager and Kill the name of the Application that's running in vs2015 then all works..also I run the application in Administrator Mode

Comment: @vishakh369 Stop making garbage edit suggestions.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio worked for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that my other running solution was referencing the same < executable path>.

Just make sure that no other process is using the referenced folder/file/dll

Comment: If you are using antivirus app such as Bitdefender. It may also cause this error. Llook its notificaitions.

Answer (score 3):

Deactivate your anti-virus for a while and try again.

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to close all processes, move the project to a different folder (on a different disk) b restart the computer and everything will work as it should. It worked for me without any problems. Hope this helps someone

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation]
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to quickly test something in a .NET Core Console Application Solution and ran into this issue due to BitDefender blocking the resulting binaries.
I've named the app `client` which actually was the culprit. Renaming my solution fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes antivirus softwares can block copying an exe file from a folder to any path. You can manage by settings or the easiest way is to shut down live protection while you are coding and debugging.
:)